# How to handle http calls in a delayed job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am implementing an json api using rails. I wish to make requests to another web service using delayed job to prevent it from blocking my rails app. So far so good. So i have a function defined in my model which does a http POST to this other web service.
 However, the other web service is is an asynchronous api with callbacks. Hence I want to also receive callbacks from this api within my delayed job. 
  Is this possible? Can I have a http listener in my delayed job whose port number I can control or know within my code?

Comment: The callback need not be part of the delayed job, why do you need that?

Comment: because the other service will tell me if it has finished / failed only if I get a callback.

Comment: agree, that is how most compute intensive web services operate. Can you not define a callback in the controller and update the model when you get the callback?

Comment: I do not want to load my rails app with the callback. My delayed job should come back with success / failure in the db. That is the aim here.